# Batman cape material

Tags: modeling

How do I create a material for Batman's cape? I have already tried a black diffuse shader, but it is not good. I need some lights highlights so I tired glossy, too much highlights. So I made roughness higher, still bad.

Comment: Welcome to Blender.SE. You're asking for a tutorial, which is outside the scope of this site. Please narrow your question...

Comment: Use the same materials for Superman's cape, but change the logo...

Answer (score 3):

Use *Mix Shaders*. To the First slot add a *Velvet Shader* with an almost black color. To the second slot add another *Mix Shader*. To the second mix shaders First slot add simply an almost black *Diffuse shader*. To the second mix shaders second slot add a brighter colored *Glossy Shader* with a high roughness. The second mix shaders *Fac* value should be low. Experiment with the two *Fac* values.